# Is it a good idea to switch Ubuntu flavours by apt removing the original one and apt installing a new one?

Tags: apt, system-installation, xubuntu, lubuntu

I installed Lubuntu, but only because that was the only Ubuntu flavour that I could put on the USB I had at the time. I originally wanted Xubuntu. I wonder if I could switch to Xubuntu by installing `xubuntu-desktop` and removing `lubuntu-desktop` (just to save some space).

Would that make my system unusable? Would it replace default software? Would it work?

Comment: it is easy to install xubuntu `sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop`. Hard to remove lubuntu, I would leave it

Comment: I agree with @Panther. You can damage the desktop environment (DE), that you want to keep, if you try to remove the other DE.

Comment: You're not likely to actually "damage" anything, but you should install the new meta-package first, prior to removing the old one. You might end up with some dangling packages installed, but should be generally OK. "Is it a good idea?" though is a subjective question, so I've voted to close this as primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem: 'I installed Lubuntu, but only because that was the only Ubuntu flavour that I could put on my USB I had at the time.'

There are workarounds for this problem: If you only have a small USB pendrive or a CD drive (not DVD), most [or all] Ubuntu and Ubuntu community flavour iso files might be too big.

- Use an Ubuntu [**`mini.iso`**](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13211730#post13211730) if you can boot in BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode).
- Use an **Ubuntu Server iso file** and and avoid installing server packages. The 64-bit server iso file makes a boot drive that can boot both in UEFI and BIOS mode.

  - If there are still problems (for example with the graphics of the installer in UEFI mode), you can try a compressed image file according to [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS).

In both cases the iso files are smaller than the iso files with graphical desktop environments (standard Ubuntu desktop and the community flavours Kubuntu, Lubuntu, ... Xubuntu).

- The `mini.iso` file sizes are very small, typically around 60 MB,
- the Ubuntu Server iso files sizes are less than 1 GB (as are most of the Lubuntu iso file sizes),
- the sizes of the other iso files with graphical desktop environments are between 1 GB and 2 GB (typically smaller than or around 1.5 GB).

You can select **`xubuntu-desktop`** during the installation, or install it afterwards, when you have booted into the text mode interface, and then you will get Xubuntu.